# Excel formula for "one calendar month" to calculate deadline for GDPR responses

Tags: excel-formula, calendar

I've been trying to create a formula in excel to calculate the deadline for a GDPR subject access response based on the date of the request.  Sounds simple??  The ICO description of how to calculate it is:-

> You should calculate the time limit from the day after you receive the request (whether the day after is a working day or not) until the corresponding calendar date in the next month.  If this is not possible because the following month is shorter (and there is no corresponding calendar date), the date for response is the last day of the following month.  If the corresponding date falls on a weekend or a public holiday, you have until the next working day to respond.  This means that the exact number of days you have to comply with a request varies, depending on the month in which the request was made."

I just can't work out how to turn this into an excel formula and will probably just settle for [date]+28 unless someone can help me please?

Best wishes,
Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to redefine the calendar month to **20 working days** then you can make use of the `WORKDAY([date],[number of working days],{[holidays]})` function like so:

`=WORKDAY([@[Date of Request]],20,BankHolidays)` - where BankHolidays is a named range containing the bank holidays...

[image]

***EDIT-***

I guess you could always use `EDATE()` to add your month, deduct a day then use `WORKDAY()` to add the day back on in the above way:

`=WORKDAY(EDATE([@[Date of Request]],1)-1,1,BankHolidays)`

Answer (score 1):

Ok - managed to work this one out by combining bits from various other similar requests:

Formula for one calendar month after a given date:

```
=DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]),MONTH([@[Date of Request]])+1,MIN(DAY([@[Date of Request]]),DAY(DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]),MONTH([@[Date of Request]])+2,0))))
```

Formula for one calendar month after the day after a given date:

```
=DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]+1),MONTH([@[Date of Request]]+1)+1,MIN(DAY([@[Date of Request]]+1),DAY(DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]+1),MONTH([@[Date of Request]]+1)+2,0))))
```

Formula for GDPR deadline (as above but move backwards if it lands on a weekend):

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]+1),MONTH([@[Date of Request]]+1)+1,MIN(DAY([@[Date of Request]]+1),DAY(DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]+1),MONTH([@[Date of Request]]+1)+2,0)))))=7,DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]+1),MONTH([@[Date of Request]]+1)+1,MIN(DAY([@[Date of Request]]+1),DAY(DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]+1),MONTH([@[Date of Request]]+1)+2,0))))+2,IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]+1),MONTH([@[Date of Request]]+1)+1,MIN(DAY([@[Date of Request]]+1),DAY(DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]+1),MONTH([@[Date of Request]]+1)+2,0)))))=1,DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]+1),MONTH([@[Date of Request]]+1)+1,MIN(DAY([@[Date of Request]]+1),DAY(DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]+1),MONTH([@[Date of Request]]+1)+2,0))))+1,DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]+1),MONTH([@[Date of Request]]+1)+1,MIN(DAY([@[Date of Request]]+1),DAY(DATE(YEAR([@[Date of Request]]+1),MONTH([@[Date of Request]]+1)+2,0))))))
```

The above answer is not elegant lol, but it does work and correct calculates the GDPR response deadline based on the date of the request.  The only thing it doesn't do is check for a bank holiday and add a day if the deadline lands on one.